# Can we use select statement with count in triggers on view table

Tags: select, count, triggers, where-clause, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write like this... but it showing error
Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_transaction5 BEFORE update ON prd
for each row
begin
select count(productname) from prd where productname = "IPad";
end//
delimiter ;
```

Need to execute the trigger using select statement